# Applying a 2D numpy mask to grayscale image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have a 256×256 px 2D mask with pixel values of either 0 or 255, and a matching grayscale image. Both have shapes (256, 256).

I'd like to apply the mask on the grayscale image so the resulting image only contains pixels from the original grayscale image, where corresponding mask values are 255 (the original grayscale pixel values should be preserved).

I'm not being able to do this using

```
img_clean = img_grayscale[mask]
```

as it adds a new dimension to the array (as mentioned in numpy's docs).

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean with `only contains pixels from the original grayscale image`?

Comment: the resulting image should be a replica of the original, **except** for those pixels in the original that have a corresponding `0` in the mask -- for those pixels, the resulting image values should be `0`

Comment: In that case bitwise AND should work: `img_clean = img_grayscale & mask`

Comment: yes perfect, if you put it as an answer I'll select it, thanks

Comment: Good idea, but it also works if the mask has a value != 255. I'm not sure if this is okay.

Comment: that's true, although these masks are 0 or 255—would there be a better way?

Answer (score 6):

Just to add a 3rd option and modify your gray scale image *inplace*:

```
img_grayscale[mask == 255] = 0
```

PS: you can just create a copy if you don't want in-place modifications.

Comment: The 3rd option and the best option

Answer (score 5):

I think this should do the job

```
np.where(mask == 255, img_grayscale, 0)
```

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html for documentation.

Comment: Most flexible since you can set the masked area to any 0-255 value (0 where).  Also, this is obviously not an inplace calc.

Answer (score 3):

A [bitwise AND](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) can be used to in order to set the pixel values to `0` where the mask is `0`:

```
img_clean = img_grayscale & mask
```

As the mask contains either `0` or `255` values are either kept the same or set to `0` as per your requirements.

Comment: Just a minor comment, but if `img_grayscale` is of a data type different from `uint8` or `img_grayscale` has intensity ranges larger than 255, this is not going to work. In most cases grayscales images are uint8 in the range of 0-255, but just in case is worth adding the note (e.g. I tend to work with float32 images in 0-1 range).